# Getting started with React, couldn't render the page passing props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I set up two objects to mock some data. I would like to print the two elements on the page, but codePen doesn't show up any error as to why it wouldn't output to the page.

App should output two h1 elements that corresponds to the object I've assigned for. Don't think i need to initalize any states there. Just using the props from obj and obj2

thank you.

```html
<div id="root">
</div>
```

```js
let obj = {
  firstName: "Bobby",
  lastName: "Lee",
};

let obj2 = {
  firstName: "Priscilla",
  lastName: "Young",
};

function Element(props) {
  return (
  <h1> Welcome back {props.identification.firstName} {props.identification.lastName} !</h1>;
  );
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Element identification={obj} />
      <Element identification={obj2} />
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: a codesandbox link could be a good starting point to get any help on such code snippets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function Element(props) {
  return (
  <h1> Welcome back {props.identification.firstName} {props.identification.lastName} !</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was a typo mistake, I was about to edit that